PowerBI: Conditional formatting general total visual table
I want to put conditional formatting for the grand total of a visual table. I would like to have the same color code for the lines present in the screenshot ("Var.Qté", "Var.CA", "Var in € CA" column) Can you help me? ex: I want the “Var in € CA” column to be green if >0 and red if <0. Thank you
enter image description here

In the Conditional Formatting options, set Apply to to Values and totals.

